# Как получить список слов, по которым нейросеть определила конкретную тему текста?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

у меня реализована на keras нейросеть для бинарной классификации,на выходе у меня возвращает ответ -  положительный или отрицательный текст. А есть ли способ возвращать слова, по которым сеть определила тот или иной класс текста?

Ну например дан текст:

"«Мстители: Война Бесконечности» это без преувеличения один из самых грандиозных, масштабных и амбициозных фильмов студии MARVEL. Это кроссовер призванный объединить в себе пути многих персонажей, свершить их судьбы, и стать кульминационной частью долгого действа. Начиная с картины «Железный человек», кинематографическая вселенная Чудес шла к этому десять лет. Получилось ли у них создать достойное завершение истории о камнях бесконечности? Чтобы корректно ответить на этот вопрос нужно взвесить все плюсы и минусы.

И дабы не тянуть дерево за стебелёк давайте уже начнём.

Не секрет, что последние фильмы Marvel грешат чрезмерным обилием шуточек, из-за которых довольно сложно бывает воспринимать некоторые драматичные моменты всерьёз. К примеру, третий фильм о Торе, имеющий подзаголовок «Рагнарёк» — конец света в германо-скандинавской мифологии, вообще был охарактеризован комедией. Поэтому, первое, за что хочется похвалить третьих «Мстителей», это баланс. Баланс между юмором и драмой, достигнутый нормативностью диалогов и отлично выдержанной атмосферой.

Также стоит сказать о персонажах. Ещё во время создания кинокартины многие опасались, что такой громоздкий пласт героев и злодеев просто затеряется на фоне основных любимчиков публики. Однако, фильм не только сумел не потерять никого из персонажей, но и уделил каждому время, дав возможность раскрыться если не полностью, то хотя бы частично дать себя распробовать.

Антагонист — слабое место всех кинокомиксов Marvel, роль, которую труднее всего прописать, и которую Marvel сливали в трубу уже огромное количество раз. Каким у них получился Танос? Великолепным. Большой, фиолетовый, точно знающий чего он хочет и идущий к своей цели, безумный титан проявляет к своим врагам не только жестокость, но и милосердие. Ему не чужды такие понятия, как любовь и семья, он способен к состраданию. Танос искренни верит в праведность своего пути, и в какие-то моменты ему хочется сопереживать.

Визуал, стоит ли о нём говорить, обсуждая дорогостоящий блокбастер от Marvel? Не думаю. Ведь достойный CGI сейчас почти что везде. Лучше сразу перейдём к разбору минусов.

Начнём с главного, того, что можно сказать лежит на поверхности — рваных краёв. Вам случалось подслушать не с начала чей-то разговор, при этом ещё умудриться не дослушать до конца и куда-то уйти? Мало вероятно, что вы поймёте о чём говорили люди, их слова и фразы будут просто вырваны из контекста, и будет сложно что, куда, зачем уразуметь. Так и с фильмом «Мстители: Война Бесконечности», для неподготовленного массового зрителя он вырван из контекста. Уловить нить происходящего, не имея представления о событиях предыдущих эпизодов сериала очень и очень сложно. Возникает путаница в связи с тем, что у людей просто происходит разрыв шаблона. Ведь существуют такие неискушённые зрители, которые никогда не слышали о каких-то там комиксах, видели до этого только фильмы о Докторе Стрендже и Человеке-Пауке, но знать не знали, что они в одной вселенной.

К тому же фильм буквально обрывается на полуслове, так и не выдав нам внятного финала. Известно, конечно, что продолжение выйдет через год, а перед ним ещё пара эпизодов сериала, но это ведь не делает фильм целостнее. Наоборот, это лишь усугубляет положение следующей части кроссовера.

Вообще, с целостностью у фильма огромные нелады. И это касается не только начала, конца или персонажей. Целостности нет в происходящем. Дело в том, что событий в фильме так много, что их не удаётся все полноценно отобразить. У нас тут и Ваканда, и Старк с Пауком и Стренджем, и Стражи Галактики. Действие постоянно метается от одной команды к другой, от персонажа к персонажу, от эпика к драме, а затем всё обратно. Да, все сцены хорошо сбалансированы, динамика происходящего развлекает и не даёт заскучать. Но всё подаётся сумбурно, вспышками, короткими сценами. Некоторыми моментами просто не удаётся насладиться, а какие-то прочувствовать.

Итог: всем, кто в теме, является фанатов комиксов, и видел если не все, то хотя бы большую часть предшествовавших фильмов — смело идти. Фильм интересный, динамичный, с качественным визуалом и дичайшим эпиком. Достойно затраченных на билет денег. Тем же, для кого кинематографическая вселенная Marvel дремучий лес, дважды подумайте зачем вы идёте на этот фильм в кино. Эпик или сюжет, что для вас, как киномана важнее?"

И слова которые должна вернуть сеть:грандиозный,интересный,динамичный,дорогостоящий и тд
т.е все слова, которые характеризуют этот отзыв как положительный. 
Как их получить?????

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Также советую ознакомиться: ["Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL / etc.?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: Интересно, много ли людей будут читать полностью вопрос?

Comment: Лучше бы вы в вопросе соответствующий код привели. Выкладывать один экземпляр из набора данных имеет смысл только в том случае если вы выложите вашу обученную и сохраненную модель. Не зная как именно устроена ваша модель, можно лишь строить догадки, а это чаще всего пустая трата времени...